# lua and "module 'gears' not found:"

Tags: module, lua, awesome-wm

I have the awesome rc.lua file , `awesome 3.5` and `lua 5.2` .When i use awesome -k i get the following result:

```
mohsen@debian:~$ awesome -k
✔ Configuration file syntax OK.
```

But when i use :

```
mohsen@debian:~$ lua .config/awesome/rc.lua 
lua: .config/awesome/rc.lua:2: module 'gears' not found:
    no field package.preload['gears']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/gears.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/gears/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/gears.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/gears/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/gears.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/gears/init.lua'
    no file './gears.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/gears.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/gears.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/gears.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './gears.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    .config/awesome/rc.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Gear is exist in :

```
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/init.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/wallpaper.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/object.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/debug.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/sort.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/surface.lua
/usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/color.lua
```

**Question:** How can i solve my problem?

Comment: Try adding `package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/awesome/lib/?/init.lua'` to your `rc.lua` at the top before `require 'gears'`.

Comment: I add it, but i get `lua: /usr/share/awesome/lib/gears/init.lua:12: module 'gears.color' not found:`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: You need `package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/awesome/lib/?/init.lua;/usr/share/awesome/lib/?.lua'`. But why are you trying to run the awesome configuration file using the standalone Lua interpreter? It is intended to be loaded by `/usr/bin/awesome` which embeds its own Lua (5.1) interpreter ...

Comment: I need to add to awesome and watch output.

Comment: Do you have better solution to debug awesome rc.lua ?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/awesome#Debugging_rc.lua

Comment: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Using_Xephyr

Comment: `Configuration file ***syntax*** OK.` refers to whether you have obvious code errors in the *syntax*, and won't really help in this case.